# Reading double digits from a file and avoiding whitespace/strings (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to read from a file and add my numbers to an array. The file can contain white spaces and strings but I only need the digits.

```
0
4
xxx
52

23
```

Here is my code so far:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
int i=0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt() && count < 15) {   //only need first 15 digits
    arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
    count+= 1;
}
```

The code currently works but it stops once it reaches a string or any whitespace.

Comment: Depends very much on your data set, whether it has several numbers in the same line, special characters etc. If you want to use your approach, you can read one integer at a time and add it to your "number-string" UNTIL a white space or NAN comes up and then convert that string into an integer.

Comment: The example I gave is as complicated as it gets, there's always either digits on a line or a string no mix.

Comment: Well, your while checks if scanner.hasNextInt, so it should stop when it comes to a situation where next token read is NOT int. You can just change the nextInt to EOF or another check to break from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` will quit when it hits the first non-integer. You need to change the condition:

```
// Loop until eof or 15 numbers
while(scanner.hasNext() && count < 15) {   //only need first 15 digits
    // Have a number?
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
        count+= 1;
    }
    // Not a number, consume.
    else {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SVN Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
while (scanner.hasNext() && count < 15) { // use Scanner::hasNext 
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {           // if is number then add it to the array
        arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
        count++;
    } else {                             
        scanner.next();                   // else ignore the value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, going to use nextLine() since my inputs are given line by line

Comment: @SVN you mentioned whitespaces, so what would happen if the line is `xx 25`? is the desired behaviour to skip the whole line?

Comment: you're right but my file only takes an int string or whitespace per line, otherwise, your method would be better.